# Microsoft Access: Sum by specific column by count

Tags: ms-access, count, sum

Data:

```
Fiscal Quarter | Organization | BU | Learners | Total by FQ
------------------------------------------------------------
    FY2016 Q2  |     CS       | CC |    12    |      2
    FY2016 Q2  |     CS       | CC |    12    |      2
    FY2016 Q3  |     CS       | CC |     5    |      1
```

I'm hoping to get a sum by Fiscal Quarter (bold data above).
 Currently have a count by Learners but can't seem to get it to the sum by the FQ without messing up the count.
[Access Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JibTK.jpg)

[Design Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u93ae.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question and show us your expected output along with the query you have already tried.

Comment: Hi Tim, please see updated question with a couple of screenshots.

Comment: I updated my answer assuming you want to sum learners by fiscal quarter.  You still didn't show us your expected output, by the way.

Comment: Hi Tim. My expected output will be in Excel which is linked to the query from Access.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
SELECT
    [Fiscal Quarter],
    SUM([Learners]) AS total_learners
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY [Fiscal Quarter]
```